# Update Stripe module at Parse Cloud Code

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code

Turns out that Stripe module at Parse Could Code is out of date and won't be updated.

Source:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/523104684492016/

> Parse modules are using an old version of the API and there is no plan
>   to update it in the near future.
>
> As a workaround please download the newer SDKs directly off the third
>   party site, place it in "cloud/" folder and import it using require();
>
> We're going to close this by design.

I have downloaded Stripe module via terminal with command

```
npm install stripe
```

I'm trying to import this module but when I deploy it to Parse, it seems that most of the modules are missing. I get errors like this:

> Update failed with Error: Module child_process.js not found
>       at node_modules/stripe/lib/stripe.js:24:12

Hope someone can point me out on how to add third party modules to Parse Cloud Code properly. Thanks.

Comment: i know nothing about this, but it seems fishy because `child_process` is a core node module

Comment: Yeah, I'm not into web development (i had no idea before about javascript or node.js, just learning on the fly because I need to integrate payments into my mobile application), so I hope someone can help me with this one.

Comment: Parse uses a modified version of express and node, so not all (I'd guess most) modules won't run in the cloud folder, especially since Parse has poor submodule support too. This is a large reason why I just run my own express apps in Heroku, since Parse's module support is extremely limited

Answer (score 2):

Seems that Parse's module support is really limited and adding submodules is impossible or too complex to even bother, that's why I decided to move to Heroku. Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a bit old, but my "workaround" was, rather than importing the module, convert the cURL requests from Stripe's documentation to Parse.Cloud.httpRequests. You can get access to the entire API that way.