# stripe cloud api module reference for parse is missing (brings up 404 page)

Tags: parse-platform

I am implementing the stripe api in parse cloud code and can successfully navigate to the page where a generic example is given (https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-modules-stripe) but when I click on the hyperlink "API reference" for it to get the full list of available functions it brings up a 404 page.

Has anyone else seen this? Is there a new location to access the documentation?

Comment: Don't know if this question is on-topic since the problem is related to being able to access a site and not to code. Bring it up with them.

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I too am having difficulties and need this resolved -- any solutions yet?

Comment: Perhaps this answers the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857178/update-stripe-module-at-parse-cloud-code